# How to disable sorting on Primefaces lazy datatable?

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-datatable

I have a datatable with lazy data model and pagination. I want to disable default sorting when I click on "search" button and enable it again when I click on "display" button. So didn't put "sortBy" in my xhtml file and instead, I set it dynamically in my backing bean.

Everything works properly until I click on the header to flip sort order between descending and ascending. It means the "search" button disables the sorting and "display" button enables it correctly if I don't click on the header. But when I click on the header and then click the "search" button, in `load` funciton of LazyDataModel, value of the argument `sortField` is `"date"` and the datatable will be sorted by date though the "date" column is not colored apparently!!

This is my datatable:

```
<h:form id="contents-form">
...
    <p:dataTable id="tbl" widgetVar="tbl" var="msg" value="#{homeController.messagesModel}" lazy="true"
                 currentPageReportTemplate="سطر {startRecord}-{endRecord} از {totalRecords}"
                 paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                 paginator="true" rows="10" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15"
                 emptyMessage="هیچ پیامکی وجود ندارد."
                 selection="#{homeController.selectedMessages}" rowSelectMode="checkbox"
                 rowKey="#{msg.id}" filteredValue="#{homeController.filteredMessage}"
                 editable="true" editMode="cell"
                 style="width:100%" dir="rtl">

        <f:facet name="header">
            <p:commandButton value="خروجی" action="#{homeController.prepareExport}" icon="fa fa-save"
                             update="export-dlg-box" oncomplete="PF('exportDlgBox').show()"/>
            <p:commandButton value="واژگان" action="#{homeController.showListTermsChart}"
                             icon="fa fa-bar-chart" update="contents-form chart-form msgs"
                             oncomplete="PF('chartDlgBox').show()"/>
        </f:facet>

        <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{homeController.onCellEdit}" oncomplete="updateDescFilter()"/>

        <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:16px;text-align:center"/>

        <p:column headerText="فرستنده" style="width:100px" filterBy="#{msg.sender.number}"
                  sortBy="#{msg.sender.number}">
            <p:commandLink action="#{homeController.setPhoneNumToShow(msg.sender)}" update="phone-form"
                           oncomplete="PF('phoneDlgBox').show()" styleClass="simple-command-link">
                <h:outputText value="#{msg.sender.number}"/>
            </p:commandLink>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="گیرنده" style="width:100px" filterBy="#{msg.receiver.number}"
                  sortBy="#{msg.receiver.number}">
            <p:commandLink action="#{homeController.setPhoneNumToShow(msg.receiver)}" update="phone-form"
                           oncomplete="PF('phoneDlgBox').show()" styleClass="simple-command-link">
                <h:outputText value="#{msg.receiver.number}"/>
            </p:commandLink>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="متن" sortBy="#{msg.text}">
            <h:outputText value="#{msg.getTrimmedText()}"/>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="زمان" style="width:100px" filterBy="#{msg.date}" sortBy="#{msg.date}">
            <f:facet name="filter">
                <p:calendar pattern="yyyy-MM-dd">
                    <p:ajax event="dateSelect" oncomplete="PF('tbl').filter()" update="tbl"/>
                </p:calendar>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{msg.getJalaliDate()}"/>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="منبع" style="width:70px" filterBy="#{msg.source}" sortBy="#{msg.source}">
            <f:facet name="filter">
                <p:selectOneMenu onchange="PF('tbl').filter()" style="width:30px; direction:ltr">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="همه" itemValue="#{null}" noSelectionOption="true"/>
                    <f:selectItems value="#{homeController.sources}" var="source"
                                   itemValue="#{source}" itemLabel="#{source}"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{msg.source}"/>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="توضیح" style="width:70px" filterBy="#{msg.description}"
                  sortBy="#{msg.description}">
            <f:facet name="filter">
                <p:selectOneMenu id="desc-filter-select" onchange="PF('tbl').filter()"
                                 style="width:30px; direction:ltr">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="همه" itemValue="#{null}" noSelectionOption="true"/>
                    <f:selectItems value="#{homeController.descriptions}" var="desc"
                                   itemValue="#{desc}" itemLabel="#{desc}"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </f:facet>
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{msg.description}"/></f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input"> <p:inputText id="desc-input" value="#{msg.description}"
                                                    style="width:85%"/></f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="جزئیات" style="width:40px">
            <p:commandLink action="#{homeController.setMessageToShow(msg)}" ajax="true"
                           update="img-dlg-box" oncomplete="PF('imgDlgBox').show()">
                <i class="fa fa-blue fa-desktop"/>
            </p:commandLink>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="مشاهده گفتگو" style="width:40px">
            <p:commandLink action="#{homeController.showConversation(msg.sender, msg.receiver)}"
                           ajax="true" update="conv-dlg-box" oncomplete="PF('convDlgBox').show()">
                <i class="fa fa-blue fa-wechat"/>
            </p:commandLink>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

My "search" button:

```
<p:commandButton value="جست‌وجو" action="#{homeController.search}" update=":contents-form:tbl msgs"
                                     icon="fa fa-search"/>
```

My "display" button:

```
<p:commandButton value="نمایش" icon="fa fa-desktop" action="#{homeController.loadArchive}"
                 update="contents-form msgs"/>
```

`search` method in the backing bean:

```
public void search() {
    if (this.selectedArchive == null) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,
                new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "خطا!", "لطفا یک مجموعه را انتخاب کنید"));
        return;
    }

    if ((this.textQuery != null && !this.textQuery.equals(""))
            || (this.selectedNodes != null && this.selectedNodes.length > 0)) {
        logger.info(String.format("searching '%s' in archive %d ...", this.textQuery, this.selectedArchive.getId()));
        List<String> selectedWords = this.getSelectedWords(this.selectedNodes);
        searchText(this.textQuery, selectedWords);
    } else {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,
                new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "خطا!", "برای جست‌وجو هیچ متنی وارد نشده و هیچ واژه‌ای انتخاب نشده است."));
        return;
    }

    extractChoices();

    // Disable default sorting:
    DataTable table = (DataTable) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent(":contents-form:tbl");
    table.setValueExpression("sortBy", null);
    table.setValueExpression("sortOrder", null);
}
```

And `loadArchive` method in the backing bean:

```
public void loadArchive() {
    if (this.selectedArchive == null) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,
                new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "خطا!", "لطفا یک مجموعه را انتخاب کنید"));
        return;
    }
    this.messagesModel = new LazyMessageModel(this.selectedArchive, true, this.messageService);

    extractChoices();

    // Enable default sorting:
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExpressionFactory ef = context.getApplication().getExpressionFactory();
    DataTable table = (DataTable) context.getViewRoot().findComponent(":contents-form:tbl");
    ValueExpression sortVe = ef.createValueExpression(context.getELContext(), "#{msg.date}", Message.class);
    table.setValueExpression("sortBy", sortVe);
    table.setSortOrder("descending");

    logger.info(String.format("archive %d loaded", (this.selectedArchive.getId())));
}
```

Spec:

- Primefaces 6.2
- JSF 2.2.14
- Java 1.8

Comment: Is it really important to have the sort by disabled in the server? Otherwise you can maybe just use CSS

Comment: @Kukeltje I do not want to disable sorting permanently. I just want to disable default sorting. How can I do it just by CSS? I think using CSS I can just disable the sort button. But I cannot tell the datatable sort the rows by my order instead of any column.

Comment: Then I totally do not get your issue. You seem to be trying to solve something that creates a problem which in turn you are trying to solve. This sounds like a http://xyproblem.info

Comment: @Kukeltje Thanks for introducing xyproblem! It was interesting! OK! My first problem (x) is: "I want to tell the datatable not to sort the rows by any column when I click the search button. And sort by date when I click the display button." Of course I mean default sort. User can sort by any column by clicking on the headers after showing the table. I would be glad by any front-end or back-end solution which solves my problem!

Comment: Just tell the `messagesModel` which button was press and do the sorting based on that.

Comment: @JasperdeVries It does not solve the problem. I want to show the table unsorted just for the first time. But I want to sort it after the user clicked any column. Indeed I want to just disable "DEFAULT" sorting not sorting at all! My problem is that the `load` method in `messagesModel` always receives `sortField = "date"` after the user clicked on "date" column in the past, even after I manually set `sortBy` null in backend. So `messagesModel` doesn't know whether the user really clicked on the "date" column or not! So it's not sufficient to tell the `messagesModel` which button was pressed.

Comment: @JasperdeVries But there is a dirty solution: Track the sort event of datatable and tell 2 things to `messagesModel`: 1. Which button is pressed (display or search?); 2. Whether the user clicked on sort button? But it's a bit dirty! Could you please tell a neat solution? :)

Comment: I was just going to say: add a sort listener for that. I'm afraid there is not going to be a cleaner way. Well, not that I know of.

Comment: @JasperdeVries Thanks any way!

Comment: @JasperdeVries I solved it! Refer to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I finally found a clean solution! Just I must reset the table in addition to setting `sortBy` null after clicking "search" button:

```
public void search() {
    // Do something ...
    DataTable table = (DataTable) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent(":contents-form:tbl");
    table.reset();
    table.setValueExpression("sortBy", null);
}
```